# Visual Studio - 2019 Unable to Start Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am working with Unity.

While in Unity, I build my program. It's a very simple program. It's simply a cube that I placed on the screen.

I clicked build and a Visual Studios Solution was created.

I open up this solution in Visual Studios 2019 and I hit Start (there is no other option besides start).

This is what appears on my screen:

[image: Logs after running the program]

[image: Error Message That Appears After Hitting Start]

How can I get rid of the error message?

**Edit:**

I am trying to play with the Hololens emulator.

This [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools) recommended not installing the tools for Unity when installing Visual Studio 2019, that’s why I fid not do so.

**Edit #2:**

Here is an image from my entire solution from Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the VS Tools for Unity?  Normally, with the tools installed, choosing debug in unity will automatically attach the debugger to the running instance of your game running in the editor.

Comment: I edited my original post, does that help?

Comment: If you want to debug in unity you need the tools...

Comment: @LunchBox the recommendation in your link only applies when using a specific Unity version (2018 LTS) so .. which Unity version are you using? Also .. it might actually only apply to build and run the app .. never used it without the Unity tools ..

Comment: The Visual Studio solution Unity generates contains 2 projects. In your screenshot, only one was built. Did the "Main" app project fail to load or perhaps isn't set as a startup project?

Comment: @Sunius I wish I could give you 1000 upvotes. I removed each project and tried running everything 1 at a time and restarting visual studio between openings.

That seemed to do the trick.Everything works fine now.

Comment: Great! You generally don't have to open them 1 at a time. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio solutions can have multiple projects inside of them. Each project generally produces a binary: an .exe, a .dll or a .lib file. If you look at the solution explorer (which you showed in your screenshot), you'll see those projects there. One of the projects will be bolded, and that is the project that is currently set as "Startup project". This is the project that Visual Studio will try to launch when you press F5 or "Start Debugging".

The reason you're getting this error is because your "Startup Project" is configured to be "Il2CppOutputProject". This project builds a .dll, and you cannot start a .dll.

To fix this, right click on "Chapter_2" project and select "Set this project as Startup Project" option. Now starting debugging should start working.